# Overposting not prevented by bind annotation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to prevent overposting from one of my Save functions.  I'm using the Bind annotation, and it doesn't appear to be working.  Perhaps it's because I'm using `FromBody` and `Bind`.  This is our first attempt to do whitelist overpost protection, and we're just setting the standard organizationally, so even other ideas might be okay.

```
[HttpPost, HttpPut]
[Route("/Claim/Save")]
public async Task<EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim> Save([FromBody, Bind(
  nameof(EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim.WarrantyId),
  nameof(EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim.ClaimId)
)] EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim claim) => 
    await _claimService.SaveClaim(claim, await _userService.GetCurrentUserRecordFromDatabase()); //here ClaimAmount is being honoured and I don't want it to be
```

Here's the test I wrote which fails because it asserts that ClaimAmount hasn't been changed:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, 34464, "/Claim/Save")]
public async Task Save_Claim_Ignores_Overposting(int warrantyId, int claimAmount, string url)
{
    var claim = new EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim()
    {
        WarrantyId = warrantyId,
    };

    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { WarrantyId = warrantyId, ClaimAmount = claimAmount });


    var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var claimResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntitiesCorporation.Model.Claim>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    Assert.True(claimResponse.ClaimAmount == 0); //Fails because ClaimAmount is now 34464.
}
```

Comment: Don't see any reason this wouldn't be working correctly, based on what you've provided. However, in general, `BindAttribute` should be avoided. It only works for create actions, anyways, and even then it can fail for all sorts of reasons. Use a view model instead, and it will just work always. Don't want `ClaimAmount` posted? Don't included it as a property on your view model. Done. No chance ever of it coming through no matter what.

Comment: Also, FWIW, APIs actions in general should never accept entities as params. This tightly couples your API to your database layer, such that you cannot change either independently. If you changed a name of a property on the entity, for example, that *immediately* breaks any call to your API. If you used a DTO instead, you can map the value from the DTO to the new property and the client doesn't need to make any changes.